# Counting number of sequences summing to target

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming, algorithm-design

This is a problem that I have been struggling to understand in a theoretical computer science book I've been reading:

> We call a sequence of $n$ integers $x_1, \dots, x_n$ *valid* if each $x_i$ is in $\{1, \dots, m\}$.
>
> How would you design a dynamic programming-based algorithm that takes in $n$, $m$ and “target” $T$ as input and outputs the number of distinct valid sequences such that $x_1 + \dots + x_n = T$? Your
> algorithm should run in time $O(m^2n^2)$. How would you design an algorithm with the same constraints, but with an $O(mn^2)$ run time?

I'm not sure how to go about designing an algorithm with these constraints. From what I have gathered, I would let $f(s, i)$ denotes the number of length-$i$ valid sequences with sum equal to $s$ for the second part of the problem, but I'm not sure where to start. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136400/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48555/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66557255/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?

Comment: We have advice and step-by-step guides on how to design dynamic programming algorithms: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  Please read those resources, follow those step-by-step instructions, and then [edit] your question to show what progress you've made and where specifically you get stuck.  "Here is an exercise-style task, I'm not sure where to start" questions often aren't very useful to others and might not fit our site's mission very well.

Comment: Your table should contain the number of subsequences of $x_1,\ldots,x_i$ summing to $s$ for every $i \leq n$ and $s \leq mn$. Computing each cell takes time $O(1)$, so the overall running time is $O(mn^2)$.